# Master key permissions - is this the intended behaviour?

Tags: xively

I have been testing the Xively APIs "List All Products" and "List All Devices".

Using a Master key with only read permission and no private access, the lists contain private products, devices and feeds. For activated devices, the lists have the default feed keys with private access and read, create, update, delete permissions.

A master key with no private access can list private objects.

A master key with only read permission returns feed keys with full permission.

Is this the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer the case. As far as I can see, these APIs now require a master key with private access and read, update, create and delete permissions.